# Why “ps aux” in Linux does not show the process whose pid=0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The process with pid=0 exits after system init?

According to this  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_process

It is called the idle process, but why is not it listed in ps aux?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is off-topic on SO but has been answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83322/45365

Comment: No, that post does not reveal why the process with pid=0 is not listed. Many programmers may be interested in it, I guess.

Comment: @Infinite No. The output of `ps` is not related to programming. That does not mean that it is not interesting for programmers, sure. There are many things programmers might be interested in but not all these things are on-topic on SO.

Comment: The post by Viktor has a plausible answer. I have voted to closed the post as well.

Comment: Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/465256/577165